# Capture multiple RGB values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a gradient applied to an element and I'm trying to get the RGB values from the background image using regexp.

```
#gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```
var elm             = document.getElementById("gradient");
var elementColor    = getComputedStyle(elm).backgroundImage;
// elementColor     = "linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 255) 100%)";
var first           = elementColor.match(/rgb\((.*)\)/)[0];
var second          = elementColor.match(/rgb\((.*)\)/)[1];
```

Using `/rgb\((.*)\)/` doesn't work, because it returns

```
"rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 255) 100%)"
```

And I'm guessing that's because there are parenthesizes occuring twice. How do I fix this? So that it returns

```
"255,0,0", "0,0,255"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is also the case in your actual code, but in the code you pasted here, you are referring to `.backgroundImage` in Javascript even though you just defined `background` in CSS. Also you're Regex matching "rgb", while your CSS code uses "rgba", which would require a different pattern of course.

Comment: @Oscar The css is irrelevant. I've checked the returned string. It's `"linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 255) 100%)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to use a single regexp to avoid using multiple lines of code to get the job done, but it seems that what I want to do is not possible with a single regexp.

And I came to understand that you can't capture (but match) if you're using `g` flag.

I've solved the problem with a one-liner.

```
elementColor.match(/\(\d+, \d+, \d+\)/g)[0].replace(/[( )]/g, "");

// "linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 255) 100%)" -> "(255, 0, 0)" -> "255,0,0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp doesn't work because `.*` matches `)` as well - as such if we modify it to `[^\)]*` it becomes what you're after:

```
var input = "background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);";
var array = input.match(/rgba\([^\)]*\)/gi);

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    console.log(array[i].match(/\((.*)\)/)[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4z8Ly/2/

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are hard. Complex regular expressions with multiple capture groups should be avoided unless they are clearly the most practical way of parsing something.

It is not clear to me they are, in this scenario. I would:

```
rgb(255, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(0, 0, 255) 100%)
```

1- Remove the parenthesis from the expression

```
string = string.replace(/[()]/g, '');
// "rgb255, 0, 0 0%, rgb0, 0, 255 100%"
```

2- Split on `rgb`:

```
parts = string.split('rgb');
// ["", "255, 0, 0 0%, ", "0, 0, 255 100%"]
```

3- The first element will always be empty, so get rid of that:

```
parts.shift()
// ["255, 0, 0 0%, ", "0, 0, 255 100%"]
```

4- Split each element by `/,? /` (optional comma, then a space):

```
parts[0].split(/,? /g)
// ["255", "0", "0", "0%", ""]
```

There you have your values, and we only needed two dead simple regular expressions.